# combining Aframe and d3.js: embed issue with different library source

Tags: d3.js, aframe

I am trying to reproduce the example that combines d3.js with a-frame objects one can find [here](https://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/8be32e6f1f32920ba841). If I reproduce it like so, it works, but my aim is to have it working in my webpage, where I embed the a-scene in a div. But I cannot have it embedded. It renders in the back ground full size.

the sources of the libraries in the example are:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/latest/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

In order to have it embedded I change the sources of the scripts from the example to

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.js"></script>
```

Now I have it embedded, but the d3.js code does not render anything. Only the scene backgorund and lightening I guess.

Therefore, I am wondering why the official d3 source is not working with a-frame, and why the embed option is not working anymore with the latest release?

same question put differently: who is mainting the cloudfare version of d3 and is there a bug in the latest version of A-frame and the embedded option?

Thanks for your time

**EDIT:**

So if I have the aframe version set to 0.1.0, I have the d3 code working but the a-scene is not embedded in my div. And if I put the 0.5.0 version I have the a-scene embedded but the d3 code is not working anymore

I put below the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DUMMY</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://samsunginter.net/a-frame-components/dist/ocean-plane.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.1.0/aframe.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="hd">
        <wicket:link>
            <img src="hidden.svg">
        </wicket:link>
        <span id="bannerTitle">dummy title</span>
    </div>
    <div id="bd">
        <div id="aSceneDiv">
            <a-scene embedded>
                <!-- Camera with customized cursor -->
                <a-camera position="0 1.8 0" cursor-visible="true" cursor-scale="2" cursor-color="#4CC3D9" cursor-offset="2" cursor-maxdistance="100" cursor-opacity="0.5" cursor-fuse="true"></a-camera>
                <a-light color="#da47da" position="0 5 0" type="ambient"></a-light>
                <a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls></a-entity>
                <a-entity light="type: point; color: #EEE; intensity: 0.5" position="0 3 0"></a-entity>
                <!-- Sky -->
                <a-sky color="#c8f8e0"></a-sky>
            </a-scene>

        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="render()" id="start">Start</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="stopRender()" id="stop">Stop</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="addGround()" id="ground">Add Ground</button>
        </div>

        <div>
            Call to a function of the wicketApplication: <wicket:container wicket:id="version">temporary text</wicket:container>.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ft">
    </div>
    <script>

        // fake data
        var data = [ 10, 20, 30, 15, 25, 35, 40,
            45, 50, 70, 100, 120, 130,
            12, 18, 22, 29, 33, 44, 59, 200]

        // we scale the height of our bars using d3's linear scale
        var hscale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
            .range([0, 3])

        // we select the scene object just like an svg
        var scene = d3.select("a-scene")

        // we use d3's enter/update/exit pattern to draw and bind our dom elements
        var bars = scene.selectAll("a-cube.bar").data(data)
        bars.enter().append("a-cube").classed("bar", true)
        // we set attributes on our cubes to determine how they are rendered
        bars.attr({
            position: function(d,i) {
                // cubes are positioned by their center so we
                // offset for their height
                var y = 1;
                // lets place the bars all around our camera
                var radius = 5;
                //var x = i - data.length/2;
                var x = radius * Math.cos(i/data.length * 2 * Math.PI)
                var z = radius * Math.sin(i/data.length * 2 * Math.PI)
                return x + " " + y + " " + z
            },
            rotation: function(d,i) {
                var x = 0;
                var z = 0;
                var y = -(i/data.length)*360;
                return x + " " + y + " " + z
            },
            width: function(d) { return 0.5},
            depth: function(d) { return 0.9},
            height: function(d) { return hscale(d)},
            opacity: function(d,i) { return 0.6 + (i/data.length) * 0.4},
            metalness: function(d,i) { return i/data.length}
        })
            .on("click", function(d,i) {
                console.log("click", i,d)
            })
            .on("mouseenter", function(d,i) {
                // this event gets fired continuously as long as the cursor
                // is over the element. we only want trigger our animation the first time
                if(this.hovering) return;
                console.log("hover", i,d)
                this.hovering = true;
                d3.select(this).transition().duration(1000)
                    .attr({
                        metalness: 0.5,
                        width: 2
                    })
            })
            .on("mouseleave", function(d,i) {
                console.log("leave",i,d)
                this.hovering = false;
                d3.select(this).transition()
                    .attr({
                        metalness: 0,
                        width: 0.5
                    })
            })
    </script>
</body>
```

**Version 0.1.0**
[image]

**Version 0.5.0**
[image]

Comment: The "latest" version of A-Frame is not recommended; it will change and can break your demos out from under you. I would stick with 0.5.0. Is this example helpful? http://bl.ocks.org/donmccurdy/2d13aa01d854ef60eac24102846a8a5f

Comment: For the the issue with the embedded option not working, I added the css code `.a-canvas { height: calc(100%);}` to have it be embedded in my div.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy, why do you load d3 from _cloudflare_? and not _d3js.org_?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy, yes, the link is usefull. It shows very well the power of combination between d3 and AFrame. when I copy paste the code and the json I have the blocks showing up without the images. I guess every thing normal here?

Comment: Don't use `/latest/aframe.min.js`, that is locked to 0.1.0. Maybe you had an issue upgrading to 0.1.0 to 0.5.0 which is a massive jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a working implementation that was suggested by some comments. Thanks to @ngokevin, I understood that

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/latest/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

is actually referencing to the 0.1.0 version. Hence changing it to 0.5.0 is the right move. This was then producing version conflicts, and therefore I changed the a-frame set up and simplified it to this

```
<div id=aSceneID>
    <a-scene>
        <a-plane static-body color="#99d8c9" height="100" width="100" rotation="-90 0 0"></a-plane>
    </a-scene>
</div>
```

and finally, to have it embedded we have to add the css code `.a-canvas { height: calc(100%);}`