# Could not render a-sky image after hiding it initially with display:none

Tags: javascript, d3.js, aframe

I'm trying to toggle display property between `div` with d3 graph and `a-scene`. If I set `a-scene` to `display: hidden` and then toggle it, the `a-scene` seems to load but `a-sky` does not show the image on toggle. However if I load the `a-scene` first and then toggle to d3 graph it seems to work.
I've also tried to set height and width to `.a-canvas` on toggle.
I want to load the d3 graph first and then toggle to a-scene.

[Here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/light-stingray) is the demo glitch for it.
Found one [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995640/combining-aframe-and-d3-js-embed-issue-with-different-library-source), and its answer does not help.

Comment: I have tried to hide the parent `div` of `a-scene` by adding event listener for the `a-scene` as below.
`document.querySelector('a-scene').addEventListener('loaded', function () {...})`
Somehow the event is not triggered most of the times when i refresh the page. Sometimes it is triggered though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with position and visibility attribute instead of display. 
Have look at this glitch remixed with your glitch. 
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/humorous-camp 
Hope this helps you.